# How to delete instance using EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a simple windows console application to test Entity Framework using VS2012 and .NET 4.5.

I added an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to create a model from my database. I use it with this syntax but how can i delete somethings?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new HKDBEntities())
        {
           int wordId=2;
          var selectedWords = (from o in context.Addresses 
                                where o.word== wordId
                                select o).FirstOrDefault(); 

           //these syntaxt is unavailable why????
           ctx.Words.Delete(word);
           ctx.DeleteObject(word);

          // i test remove method but works not gave me some error
             context.Words.Remove(selectedWords);
        }
    }
```

How can I use delete syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Use this one : ctx.Words.Remove(word) . And dont forget to SaveChanges(); before disposing context.
!!!!!!!I have renewed the answer!!!!!!
New idea about this isue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ctx = new HKDBEntities())
        {
           int wordId=2;
          // This will get the first Addresses which have a `Words` with `WordId`==2
          var selectedWords = ctx.Addresses.First(e=>e.Words.WordId==wordId); 
          //If you want to get to selectedWords the `Words` entity and delete it you should use:
          selectedWords = cts.Words.First(e=>e.WordId == wordId);

          ctx.Words.Remove(selectedWords);
          ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

You was trying to access the remove the data from ctx while you get the data from context

Comment: int wordId=2;
              var selectedWords = (from o in context.Addresses where o.word== wordId select 0).FirstOrDefault(); i test this way but gave me error

              context.word.Remove(selectedWords);

Comment: You delete from the wrong entity. Try this ctx.Addresses.Remove(selectedWords);

Comment: i test this example on vs 2010 and entity 4.1 all these syntax works why they do not works on entity 5??ctx.Words.Delete(word);
           ctx.DeleteObject(word);

Comment: Now i get the answer. You take from your DB not `Words` entity but `Addresses` entity thats why you cant use context.Words.Remove(selectedWords); you should use context.Addresses.Remove(selectedWords);

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ctx.Words.Remove(word);`

Comment: int wordId=2;
              var selectedWords = (from o in context.Addresses where o.word== wordId select 0).FirstOrDefault(); i test this way but gave me error

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ConsoleApplication2.words>.Remove(ConsoleApplication2.words)' has some invalid arguments G:\xxx/Program.cs 18 15 ConsoleApplication2

Comment: Well, you are passing `selectedWords` to the `Remove` method. `selectedWords` is an `IEnumerable<words>` but the method needs a `words` instance. Try this: `foreach(var word in selectedWords) ctx.Words.Remove(word);`

Comment: i test this example on vs 2010 and entity 4.1 all these syntax works why they do not works on entity 5??ctx.Words.Delete(word);
           ctx.DeleteObject(word);

Comment: @motevallizadeh: Because the API changed. Simple as that.